# Privoxy: How to do user-authentification?

Tags: proxy, authentication, privoxy

Hy,
I'm running Privoxy on my server and I only want to allow some users to use the proxy. I can't specify a IP-Address because they are dynamic. I also can't use ssh because those users use mobile devices where no ssh-client is available.

I know the Proxy-Protocol can use authenticated access to the server, does Privoxy support this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having read over the Privoxy Documentation I'd tend to say that this isn't possible since Privoxys ACL System is based on per IP/per Location base.

Answer (score 0):

This can be found in the official docs:

7.4.9. enable-proxy-authentication-forwarding

Privoxy itself does not support proxy authentication, but can allow clients to authenticate against Privoxy's parent proxy.

[proxy authentication through Privoxy](https://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/config.html)